# I want to convert short to byte with following approach

Tags: c#, java, android, byte

I am using following approach for converting byte to short,

```
        short shortvalue;
        nTempByteArr[0] = RawDataQueue.poll();
        nTempByteArr[1] = RawDataQueue.poll();
        ShortValue = (short) (((nTempByteArr[1] & 0xff) << 8) | (nTempByteArr[0] & 0xff));
```

How to convert short value to exact same two byte nTempByteArr[0]  and nTempbyteArr[1]

I have tried:

```
                   nByteArr[0]     = (byte)((ShortValue & 0xff00) >> 8);
                   nByteArr[1]     = (byte)(ShortValue & 0xff);   



                  nByteArr[0]     = (byte)( ShortValue & 0xff);
                  nByteArr[1]     = (byte)((ShortValue & 0xff00) >> 8);
```

Please  help me...!!!!!!!!!!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use another approach without bit shift to convert `bytes` to `short` without shift by using `java.nio.ByteBuffer`

```
ByteBuffer bb = ByteBuffer.allocate(2);
bb.order(ByteOrder.LITTLE_ENDIAN);
bb.put(nTempByteArr[1]);
bb.put(nTempByteArr[0]);
short shortVal = bb.getShort(0);
```

and we can use the `get` function of `ByteBuffer` will help us back to get `bytes`

```
bb.putShort(ShortValue);
nTempByteArr[0] = bb.get(0);
nTempByteArr[1] = bb.get(1);
```

Comment: Upvote for novel approach.  Though ultimately much lower performing than a simple shift operation.

Answer (score 0):

```
short s = ...

byte b1 = (byte)((s >> 8) & 0xff);
byte b2 = (byte)(s & 0xff);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

### short to byte

(number >>> 8) & 0xFF;
(number >>> 0) & 0xFF;

### byte to short

(short) ((portArray[0] << 8) | (portArray[1]) & 0xff);

Answer (score 0):

My Solution is correct . There was some other problem because of that only it was not able  to  get  correct byte